# How to get Select to display proper label after selection in React.js Material-UI?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

#### Goal

I want my select menu to look like the below image (after selection). Notice the label breaks up the outline. [Documentation.](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/#simple-select)

[image]

#### Current

What I have instead is this. Notice how the outline does not break and interferes with reading the label.

[image]

Here's the code.

```
const typeConfig = [
  { value : 'question'   , label : 'Question'        , icon : 'contact_support' , } ,
  { value : 'comment'    , label : 'Comment'         , icon : 'comment'         , } ,
  { value : 'suggestion' , label : 'Suggestion'      , icon : 'feedback'        , } ,
]

const getTypeSelect = () =>
  <FormControl variant="outlined" fullWidth>
    <InputLabel ref={inputLabel} htmlFor="select">{typeLabel}</InputLabel>
    <Select
      value={type} onChange={handleChangeType}
      input={<OutlinedInput labelWidth={labelWidth} name="select" id="select" />}
    >
      {
        typeConfig.map( item =>
          <MenuItem className="align-middle" key={item.value} value={item.value}>
            <ListItemIcon className="inline align-middle">
              <Icon>{item.icon}</Icon>
            </ListItemIcon>
            <Typography
              className="inline align-middle" variant="inherit"      
              display="inline" noWrap
            >
              {item.label}
            </Typography>
          </MenuItem>
      )}
    </Select>
  </FormControl>
```

Note: I'm using Material-UI v3

Note: I am also getting this weird overlay effect when the focus moves to another form element. It's not necessary to address the below problem in your answer as I will ask a separate question for it if it's not solved with this question. I only mention it just to supply more complete information.

[image]